# Laravel Чем грозит использование прямых запросов к БД?

Tags: php, mvc, laravel, orm, eloquent

Чем грозит использование прямых запросов к БД через DB::select() ?
Мне проще написать запрос на SQL или написать сложную процедуру в БД, чем использовать правила Eloquent ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовать привязку параметров в запросах, то инъекция не пройдёт:

```
DB::select('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', array($userId));
```

Опасность представляет непосредственная вставка пользовательских данных:

```
DB::query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ' . $userId); // НИКОГДА так не делайте!
```

Я солидарен с вами в отказе от ORM, и всегда использую parameter binding.

Comment: Спасибо, возьму на заметку

Comment: ORM это не только и не столько защита от SQL инъекций, сколько инструмент абстракции, позволяющий снизить локальную сложность выборки данных

Comment: При вопросе ТС «Чем грозит...» я подумал в первую очередь о безопасности.

Comment: Минусующему: чем вреден этот ответ?

Comment: @Sergiks, я уже указал выше, почему не считаю ответ верным. Минус мой.

Comment: Повторюсь: ORM - не средство защиты от SQL инъекций. Ни слова о плюсах/минусах ORM в ответе нет, раз так -- ответ бесполезен, потому и минус.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Предложение с вопросительным знаком, дословно: «Чем грозит использование прямых запросов к БД через DB::select() ?»

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35190/discussion-between-dmitriy-simushev-and-sergiks).

Answer (score 14):

Плюсы от использования ORM:

- Меньше соблазна написать незащищенный код, который будет страдать от SQL-инъекций и тому подобных багов.
- ORM задает протоколы общения между несвязанными между собой командами. Допустим, две команды делают два модуля, работающие с одной и той же базой данных. Но одна из них в России, а другая в США, поэтому общаются они в течение 30 минут раз в день, утром. Без фанатичной дисциплины они понапишут на SQL такого, что потом это будет очень сложно стыковать между собой.
- В ORMах (в т.ч. Eloquent) UPDATE очень похож на INSERT, это позволяет уменьшить логическое дублирование кода.
- В случае работы со вложенными структурами, в ORM гораздо проще писать UPDATE, он возьмет на себя всю работу.
- В случае хорошего знания инструментов, написание тривиального кода на ORM занимает очень мало времени и серьезно ускоряет разработку в стиле "добавить 9000 фич до вечера".  Грубо говоря, если вся твоя работа - это писать админки с веб-интерфейсом, делающим CRUD, ORM может помочь тебе выдавать в 10 раз больше кода и стать сотрудником года :-)
- Весь код написан на одном языке и лежит в одном месте. Нужно меньше заботиться о deployment-части проблемы. Если все находится в коде на основном языке программирования, все что нужно для обновления - это git и средства накатывания миграций, если же они хоть как-то завязаны на базу, то мгновенно появляется проблема разворачивания. Это не очень важно, когда у тебя 1 база данных и 3 хранимых процедуры, но когда тебе нужно поддерживать в живом состоянии кластер дублирующихся микросервисов - это может стать головной болью.
- В каком-то виде имеется информация о структуре запросов, что может помочь, например, при написании собственных инструментов миграции.
- Код, написанный с использованием ORM, относительно легко портировать на разные виды баз данных. Синтаксис запросов к БД может очень отличаться между разными базами данных. Не всем нужна эта фича, но когда нужна - это критично.

Минусы использования ORM:

- Полученные запросы почти наверняка будут медленными. Особенно это касается PHP. Вполне возможно, придется заниматься профилировкой и оптимизацией в тех местах, где на чистом SQL не пришлось бы задумываться вообще.
- В ORM часто встречаются баги, поправить которые самостоятельно сложно, из-за огромной сложности кода самого ORM. Иногда сами создатели ORM не знают хороших ответов на сложные вопросы, в результате пользователям остается только искать обходные пути.
- На клиент часто вытягиваются данные, которых там быть не должно, что делает некоторые задачи просто невыполнимыми. Например, генерацию банковской опердени, которая в stored procedure отрабатывает в течение целого дня, проводя операции над всей базой целиком, может оказаться вообще невозможно написать в рамках ORM.
- Предыдущие знания о хаках SQL будут помогать очень редко. Гениальный написатель SQL-скриптов будет чувствовать себя закованным цепями в темнице сырой.
- Не всё, что можно сделать с помощью специальных функций БД, можно повторить в ORM. Это может быть не только минусом, но и благом, в зависимости от точки зрения.
- ORM нужно изучать. Знания, приобретенные в Hibernate навряд ли помогут в Active Record или Eloquent.

Как всегда, использование или неиспользование ORM есть инженерный компромисс, и нужно четко понимать, что и зачем вы делаете.

Предполагаю, что SQL удобно использовать в двух случаях - простых скриптах уровня Hello World, и наоборот - в случае необходимости серьезных оптимизаций.

В обычных проектах, особенно в тех, где участвует большая географически распределенная команда, лучше использовать ORM как средство устранения хаоса и упрощения написания кода.

Comment: Блестящий ответ! Спасибо)

Answer (score 5):

На самом деле, ORM это не единственный путь абстрагирования от "чистых" SQL запросов со всеми их плюсами/минусами. Существует еще один слой абстракции, позволяющий с одной стороны избавиться от SQL кода в приложении, а с другой не вносить лишних усложнений в проект. Я говорю о концепции *Query Builder*.

*Query Builder* -- это дополнительный слой абстракции, который позволяет строить SQL запросы через объектный интерфейс. *Query Builder* позволяет практически полностью абстрагироваться от различий в диалектах SQL для различных БД.

Плюсы использования *Query Builder*'а:

- Относительная простота перехода от одной БД к другой.
- Простота и гибкость динамического конструирования запросов.
- Возможность модификации запроса "на лету" без необходимость заниматься
  разбором строки SQL.
- Написать код, подверженный SQL-инъекциям сложнее (хотя все еще возможно), потому что конкатенация строк при построении запроса не используется в явном виде.
- Можно использовать большинство приемов оптимизации SQL запросов.

Минусы использования *Query Builder*'а:

- Дополнительный слой абстракции несколько усложняет приложение.
- Необходимо изучить API еще одной сторонней библиотеки.

В Laravel, есть даже специальный сервис реализующий концепцию [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries). Существуют и другие реализации *Query Builder*, например,  [Doctrine DBAL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html), который можно использовать независимо от фреймворка.